# How to store the sql result into a variable?

Tags: php, sql

Why isn't this working for me:

```
$item_id =
"SELECT item_id FROM items WHERE item_id=(SELECT max(item_id) FROM items)";
```

I'm trying to insert the sql query result into the variable `item_id`.

If i write `echo"$item_id";` i get the sentence in between the quotes as an output.

Comment: Read a tutorial on using SQL (make sure it covers `mysqli` or `PDO`, but not the obsoleted `mysql` functions). You "get the sentence" because you created a string that contains SQL, but otherwise *did nothing* with the string.

Comment: What are you using, PDO, `mysqli`, or `mysql`?

Comment: For instance, see http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers , http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php (I recommend PDO because it allows one to use *Exceptions for error handling*) , http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/54239-introduction-to-mysqli-and-prepared-statements/ , http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should etc. YMMV. Avoid the obsoleted `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: @EduLomeli That's what i meant in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

you must have to do the connection out from the var and you need to do a fetch array
try this:

// your connection data //

> $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "youruser");
> mysql_select_db("yourdb", $link);

// your select //

> $result = mysql_query("SELECT yourvalue FROM yourtable", $link);
>
> $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)

your item var

> $item_id = $row ["yourvalue"]

regards

Comment: i get this error:
`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Comment: change , `mysql_fetch_array($result)` for `mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` im not sure about your select sentence, try to do something more simple, if it works try, your select max, let me know if it works regards..